# SpreeCommerce - cannot create new user in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am building an ecommerce solution using spree to handle products/orders etc.
I am having a little trouble figuring how to create spree entries through my signup controller. The user fills a form out and then it is supposed to:

1) create a new user object with addresses

2) create a new order for that user + add a subscription product to that order

3) Create a stripe customer and add a stripe plan

4) Redirect to a confirmation page.

I can't seem to find much in the way of documentation for integrating with spree from a custom rails setup (only overriding their templates).

The issue I am having is that I am not seeing the new user object being created. I pulled this code from the backend and modified it to create a new user when the signup form is submitted:

```
user_params = {"email" => emailAddress,"password"=> password}

spreeUser = Spree.user_class.new(user_params)

spreeUser.save
```

This isn't adding any new user to the DB. I have also tried through the api endpoint POST api/users but still no luck.

Is it possible to use spree in this way and if so what am I doing wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Spree does not have a user class built in. You need to either (1) use the [Spree Auth Devise gem](https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise), (2) use another gem like regular Devise to create a user class or (3) create your own. If you do (2) or (3), you then set up Spree to recognize that user class.

This [Spree documentation](https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/authentication.html) walks you through how to do just that.